# Most efficient way of getting all records within an 2 hour window

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to write a query that based on two date fields finds where there is a 2 hour or greater difference.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(Date_Fielda, 'DD-MON-YY HR24:MI:SS'), 
       TO_DATE(Date_Fieldb, 'DD_MON-YY, HR24:MI:SS')
FROM   DUAL;
```

how would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you would select from a table and use a `where` clause.  Here is a simple method in Oracle:

```
select t.*
from t
where abs(date_columna - date_columnb) > 2 / 24
```

If you know that one column comes earlier than the other, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where date_columna > date_columnb + interval '2 hour'
```